# How to replace a set of x axis labels with another one

Tags: r, plot

I am plotting roughly 300 variables, R automatically sets x-axis labels and has them as numbers, I don't want this. But if I use the xaxt = 'n' feature and then 'axis', it won't work because for axis I'll need to define x labels for 300 variables to....
Is there any way to fix this?
To give a better example of my issue, my code looks something like this:

```
plot(data, xaxt = 'n')
x = c("Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3", "Time 4", "Time 5", "Time 6")
axis(side = 1, at = 1:6, labels = x[1:6])
```

But this is not working, I think it has to do with the fact that I have 300 data points, not 6, but I just want it to equally space out these 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at` should contain 6 numbers between 1 and 300 at which you want the labels to be placed, not just 1 through 6, because this will squash them all at the beginning/left side.

```
dat=rnorm(300)
plot(dat, xaxt="n")
x=c("Time 1", "Time 2", "Time 3", "Time 4", "Time 5", "Time 6")
axis(1, at=floor(seq(1,300,length=6)), labels=x)
```

[image]